# Azure AKS User Credentials Login to K8 Dashboard and RBAC Built-in Roles

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-rbac

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/aks/control-kubeconfig-access#available-cluster-roles-permissions), Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role allows access to Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action API call only.

My user is part of an AD group that has `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role` permissions on the AKS cluster and all the cluster role and cluster role bindings have been applied via `kubectl`.

I can double check and verify that access to dashboard and permissions work with these steps:

```
 1. az login
 2. az aks get-credentials --resource-group rg --name aks
 3. kubectl proxy
 4. Open web connection
 5. Get prompt on terminal to login via device code flow
 6. Return to web connection on dashboard
 7. I can correctly verify that my permissions apply, 
 i.e. deleting a job does not work and this falls in line with my
    kubectl clusterrole bindings to the Azure AD group.
```

However when I try to use the `az aks browse` command to open the browser automatically like this, i.e. without `kubectl proxy`:

```
 1. az login
 2. az aks get-credentials --resource-group rg --name aks
 3. az aks browse --resource-grouprg --name aks
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
The client 'xxx' with object id 'yyyy' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/read' over scope 
'/subscriptions/qqq/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/aks' 
or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

A `dirty` solution was to apply `Reader` role on the AKS cluster for that AD group - then this issue goes away but why does `az aks browse` require `Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/read` permission and why is that not included in `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role`?

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the command

`az aks browse --resource-grouprg --name aks` isn't working with the more recent version of AKS, you can find the full details here.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23789

Also, your current problem might also be that your user XXX doesn't have the right IAM access level at the Subscription/ResourceGroup level.